# How to detect the model type of an item in an array of query results

Tags: plugin-craftcommerce, entrymodel, models

When querying multiple model types (entries, Commerce products and Commerce variants) I want to be able to detect the model type of each item as I iterate over the results array.

Ideally to avoid this sort of error:

```
Craft\EntryModel and its behaviors do not have a method or closure named
```

There doesn't seem to be a clean way of doing this but I may be wrong!

Comment: Are you doing this from PHP or from Twig?

Comment: From Twig, hence the confusion...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Twig doesn't have a native "instanceof" check, but it'd be pretty trivial to create a [simple plugin](https://pluginfactory.io/) that added a Twig Extension where you can add an [instanceof](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/internals2.opcodes.instanceof.php) test.

```
public function getTests()
{
    return array(
        'instanceof' =>  new \Twig_Function_Method($this, 'isInstanceof')
    );
}

public function isInstanceof($var, $instance)
{
    return  $var instanceof $instance;
}
```

Then from your template, you'd do something like:

```
{% if value is instanceof('Commerce_ProductModel') %}
```

Comment: Thanks Brad, I was hoping for a solution in Twig but this will do nicely!